# Datepicker formatting to UK format when already UK

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

In WPF I have a datepicker with the following text style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
                Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy', 
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}"
                         Foreground="white"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The datepicker item itself looks like this

```
<DatePicker x:Name="datepickShowDate" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="white" CalendarStyle="{StaticResource styleCalendar}" 
    FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="139"/>
```

If I select a date from the popout calendar then the date is displayed fine.
However, if I type in a date, it appears to assume I am entering in US format and converts to UK.

i.e. if I want to type in 5th June 2018 like 05/06/2018, on clicking out of the field it suddenly becomes 06/05/2018.

My question is, is there any way of defining what the input format will be rather than just what the date should look like after date selection?

Comment: Thanks for the responses both of you...the sample code provided will be useful in future projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the `StringFormat` does not affect the value received from user input.

From [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Windows_Data_BindingBase_StringFormat):

> Gets or sets a string that specifies how to format the binding if it
>   displays the bound value as a string.

I believe there is more robust solution, but I did not find anything that could solve this problem without using converters.

```cs
public class DateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var dateTime = (DateTime?)value;
        if (!dateTime.HasValue)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        var format = (string)parameter;
        return dateTime.Value.ToString(format, culture);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var format = (string)parameter;
        DateTime dateTime;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact((string)value, format, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
        {
            return dateTime;
        }
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

The trick here is that in the `ConvertBack` method, the `DateTime.TryParseExact` is used, passing the format as an argument.

But there is a drawback - you can work with only one format - dd/MM/yyyy. If you enter something like 2018-04-29 - it won't work.

In order to use this converter you need to declare it in resources:

```xml
<local:DateTimeConverter x:Key="converter"/>
```

And use `ConverterParameter` instead of `StringFormat` (although you can use `StringFormat`, it will be used after the converter is applied):

```
Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, 
      RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}},
      Converter={StaticResource converter}, 
      ConverterParameter='dd/MM/yyyy'}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom `DatePicker`:

```
public class UkDatePicker : DatePicker
{
    private DatePickerTextBox _datePickerTextBox;
    private const string _shortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    private readonly CultureInfo _formatProvider = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

    public UkDatePicker()
    {
        Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(_formatProvider.IetfLanguageTag);
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        _datePickerTextBox = Template.FindName("PART_TextBox", this) as DatePickerTextBox;
        if (_datePickerTextBox != null)
        {
            _datePickerTextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding(nameof(DatePicker.SelectedDate))
            {
                RelativeSource = new RelativeSource() { AncestorType = typeof(DatePicker) },
                StringFormat = _shortDatePattern
            });
            _datePickerTextBox.TextChanged += dptb_TextChanged;
        }
    }

    private void dptb_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dt;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(_datePickerTextBox.Text, _shortDatePattern, _formatProvider,
            DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
        {
            SelectedDate = dt;
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample XAML:**

```
<local:UkDatePicker DockPanel.Dock="Top" SelectedDate="{Binding Date}"/>

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 10 0 0">
    <TextBlock Text="Selected Date: " FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat=dd/MM/yyyy}" FontSize="16"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**View Model:**

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DateTime? _date;
    public DateTime? Date
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set { _date = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```